# SQL Performance, Execution plan showing mostly Index Scan instead of Index Seek

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I am running below query, which is returning mostly 25 records. But it is taking almost 20 seconds. Also the total number of records in the table is less than 400,000.

```
SELECT * FROM Tickets 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HouseAccounts ON (Tickets.lHouseAccount_ID = HouseAccounts.lAccountID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers ON (Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vehicles ON (Tickets.lVehicleID = Vehicles.lVehicleID) 
WHERE (Tickets.sTicket_Number) NOT LIKE 'ADJ%' AND dbo.DateOnly(Tickets.dtCreated) between DATEADD(day, -60, dbo.DateOnly(GETDATE())) 
and dbo.DateOnly(GETDATE()) AND (Tickets.bDeleted = 0 or Tickets.bDeleted IS NULL)
```

Below is the Tickets table structure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tickets](
 [Ticket_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [lLocationID] [int] NULL,
 [dtCreated] [datetime] NULL,
 [dtUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
 [dtIn] [datetime] NULL,
 [dtOut] [datetime] NULL,
 [sTicket_Number] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [dblTotal] [float] NULL,
 [dblTaxes] [float] NULL,
 [dblTendered] [float] NULL,
 [dblChangeDue] [float] NULL,
 [bPaid] [smallint] NULL,
 [bCash] [smallint] NULL,
 [bCreditCard] [smallint] NULL,
 [bGiftCard] [smallint] NULL,
 [bHouseAccount] [smallint] NULL,
 [lHouseAccount_ID] [int] NULL,
 [sUserName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [lUserID] [int] NULL,
 [lShiftNumber] [int] NULL,
 [imgSignature] [image] NULL,
 [sSignatureFileName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [sPlate] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [sMake] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [sCarNumber] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [sDriverName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
 [sZipcode] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
 [sAge] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [sGender] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [sFleetCard] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [sFleetCardExp] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
 [bCheck] [smallint] NULL,
 [lVIPAccountID] [int] NULL,
 [lPointsThisVisit] [float] NULL,
 [lGreeterID] [int] NULL,
 [lCustomerID] [int] NULL,
 [lVehicleID] [int] NULL,
 [lWorkOrderID] [int] NULL,
 [sWorkOrderNumber] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
 [sVehicleMake] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [sVehicleColor] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [sVehicleState] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
 [sVehiclePlate] [nvarchar](9) NULL,
 [sVehicleDamage] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [sCustomerName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [dtReturnDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [lOdometer] [int] NULL,
 [sRoomNumber] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
 [sSpaceNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [bExpressTicket] [smallint] NULL,
 [lRateStructureId] [int] NULL,
 [sRateStructure] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
 [mRate] [money] NULL,
 [mSurcharge] [money] NULL,
 [mValidation] [money] NULL,
 [mPrepaid] [money] NULL,
 [mRefund] [money] NULL,
 [mMisc] [money] NULL,
 [bVoided] [smallint] NULL,
 [bCheckedOut] [smallint] NULL,
 [bClosedOut] [smallint] NULL,
 [bRefunded] [smallint] NULL,
 [lParkerId] [int] NULL,
 [bUpdated] [smallint] NULL,
 [bIndoor] [smallint] NULL,
 [iTimesPrinted] [smallint] NULL,
 [bAudit] [bit] NULL,
 [bArchived] [bit] NULL,
 [lCounterId] [int] NULL,
 [bPaymentOther] [bit] NULL,
 [sPaymentDescription] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [bScanned] [bit] NULL,
 [bPrinted] [bit] NULL,
 [bReversed] [bit] NULL,
 [sCashierTerminal] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [sGreeterTerminal] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [bLocked] [bit] NULL,
 [bWash] [bit] NULL,
 [bDeleted] [bit] NULL,
 [sDeletedBy] [nvarchar](125) NULL,
 [dtClosed] [datetime] NULL,
 [lCloserId] [int] NULL,
 [lCloserId2] [int] NULL,
 [bBarcodeScanned] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [aaaaaTickets_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [Ticket_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 65) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tickets] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Tickets__dblTota__014935CB]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [dblTotal]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tickets] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Tickets__bPaid__023D5A04]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bPaid]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tickets] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Tickets__bCash__03317E3D]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bCash]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tickets] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Tickets__bCredit__0425A276]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bCreditCard]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tickets] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Tickets__bGiftCa__0519C6AF]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [bGiftCard]
GO
```

And, here is the index and execution plan-

[image]

[image]

I have already tried with Update Statistics and updating indexes. However, nothing helped. Please suggest, how can I improve the performance of the query.

[Execution Plan.sqlplan](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AonWQQoVCBS-bsgV83cp9U9uXLY)

[Execution Plan.xml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AonWQQoVCBS-b1dO2Ul8G961-as)

[Indexes.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AonWQQoVCBS-cK9-PEYG_AflLnU)

Comment: 1st - nice job on including the DDL as well as the execution plan, that rarely happens. 2. Is there any way to include the saved execution plan as a file so we could open it for ourselves? That would be more beneficial I believe.

Comment: Also a copy/paste of the indexes as text would be better than a screenshot, that screenshot is not very legible (both of them for that matter). The index DDL is also ok if that is easier.

Comment: Neither of the predicates on `Tickets`, nor their combination, can be efficiently implemented by index seek on the existing indexes, so index scan comes at no surprise.

Comment: @Igor - Uploaded the files you need. Let me know what you find it. I would prefer if I can make some changes to DB (Table/Index) rather than actual query.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid scalar and multistatement UDFs if possible, because they are slow. And You should definitely avoid them in conditions, because they are not sargable. Replacing `dbo.DateOnly(` with `Convert(date,` should help.

The thing I am curious about - are there tickets from the future? And if there are, You really want to skip them? Chances are, You can replace that `between` with simple `Tickets.dtCreated >= convert(date, DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()))`.

Comment: Is there any suggestion I can improve on DB side, as query is inaccessible.

Comment: Sql server does not have inline scalar UDF, so for optimizer it is black box by design. I do not see way to improve that without changing the query.